# How to use two columns in x-axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using the below code to get **Segment** and **Year** in **x-axis** and **Final_Sales** in **y-axis** but it is throwing me an error.

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
%matplotlib inline

order = pd.read_excel("Sample.xls", sheet_name = "Orders")
order["Year"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(order["Order Date"]).year
result = order.groupby(["Year", "Segment"]).agg(Final_Sales=("Sales", sum)).reset_index()

bar = plt.bar(x = result["Segment","Year"], height = result["Final_Sales"])
```

**ERROR**

[image]

Can someone help me to correct my code to see the output as below.

**Required Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- When using several columns to index a dataframe you want to pass a list of columns to `[]` (see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)) as follows :

```
result[["Segment","Year"]]
```

- From the figure you provide it looks like you want to use year as *hue*. `matplotlib.barplot` doesn't have a hue argument, you would have to build it manually as described [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py). Instead you can use `seaborn` library that you are already importing anyway (see https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
sns.barplot(x = 'Segment', y = 'Final_Sales', hue = 'Year', data = result)
```

Comment: thanks for that, i've modified my code. But how to get labels at the top of every bar?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like there is no seaborn-supported solution, but you can do it manually, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62002434/how-to-add-data-labels-to-seaborn-barplot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add another pair of brackets - `result[["Segment","Year"]]`,
What you tried to do is to retrieve column named - "Segment","Year",
But actually what are you trying to do is to retrieve a list of columns - ["Segment","Year"].